# Simple switch case with foreach loop

Tags: php

I have the following PHP.

Ultimately, I'd like my Output at the end of the execution to be:

`Size1Size3`

```
$footballTypes = "1,3";

$footballTypeNames = "";

foreach ( $footballTypes as $data ) {
    switch ($data) {
      case 1:
        $footballTypeNames .= "Size 1";
      case 2:
        $footballTypeNames .= "Size 2";
      case 3:
        $footballTypeNames .= "Size 3";
    }
}

echo $footballTypeNames;
```

However, right now, I get the error:

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\football.php on line 7`

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `$footballTypes` is a string, not an array. change to `$footballTpes = [ 1, 3 ,];`

Comment: I have a feeling you can completely avoid the switch case.

Comment: @vivek_23 I'm interested, how would I do this? Is it more efficient? I have around 50 options in total but only showed a small excerpt for the question above.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Could you show how the options are arranged? With respect to efficiency, a switch case is a bit faster than what I am thinking but maybe we can make your code less verbose.

Comment: if you had an associate array `1=> "Size 1"` etc this would be so simple

Comment: `"Size $data"`…?!

Comment: Get more example for [explode and implode](https://eval.in/1119564)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) mate,

```
$footballTypes     = explode(",", "1,3"); // here I explode
$footballTypeNames = "";
foreach ($footballTypes as $data) {
    switch ($data) {
        case 1:
            $footballTypeNames .= "Size 1";break;
        case 2:
            $footballTypeNames .= "Size 2";break;
        case 3:
            $footballTypeNames .= "Size 3";break;
    }
}
echo $footballTypeNames;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/uWDgN).

There are various ways to achieve this if you are ok,
1.

```
$footballTypes     = explode(",", "1,3"); // here I explode
$temp = implode("",array_map(function($value){
    return "Size $value";
}, $footballTypes));
print_r($temp);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/cjiQ1)

Comment: Strange. When I run that code, I get the following output: `Size 1Size 2Size 3Size 3`

Comment: Still It won't produce the desired output, you are missing `break;` statement

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari Refresh page. I think its not reflected at your end.

Comment: Yeah, now it's been reflected.

Answer (score 4):

You dont need switch as your added text is `Size` only . Use explode and implode ..

> The implode() function returns a string from the elements of an array. 
>    **Syntax: implode(separator,array)**
>
> The explode() function breaks a string into an array. **Syntax: explode(separator,string,limit)**

```
$footballTypes = "1,2,3";

$footballTypeNames = implode('Size ', explode(',',$footballTypes));


echo 'Size '.$footballTypeNames;
```